wgpu buffer size overrun while applying gaussian blur filter
I recently started to learn Rust, and I decided to learn by porting a project to Rust. The source code is available publicly.
I first encountered an alignment issue. I tried some changes to bytes_per_row variable and that went away.
wgpu error: Validation Error

Caused by:
  In CommandEncoder::copy_buffer_to_texture
    Copy error
      Bytes per row does not respect `COPY_BYTES_PER_ROW_ALIGNMENT`

While the gaussian blur compute shared starting working for images that have 2^x width and height, it fails for random width height saying that copying data will end up in buffer overrun.
wgpu error: Validation Error

Caused by:
  In CommandEncoder::copy_buffer_to_texture
    Copy error
      Copy of 0..317316 would end up overrunning the bounds of the Source buffer of size 279000

I also get weirdly buffered images when blur value is high. Since the code is async, am I not blocking properly before the buffer is written?

Steps to reproduce
MRE
Test image: test.png
use image::{DynamicImage, ImageBuffer, Rgba};
use wgpu::{DeviceDescriptor, RequestAdapterOptions};
use wgpu::util::DeviceExt;

const GAUSSIAN_BLUR_SHADER: &str = r"
struct Kernel {
    sum: f32,
    size: u32,
    values: array<f32>,
};

@group(0) @binding(0) var<storage, read> kernel: Kernel;
@group(1) @binding(0) var input_texture: texture_2d<f32>;
@group(1) @binding(1) var output_texture: texture_storage_2d<rgba8unorm, write>;

@compute @workgroup_size(8, 8, 1)
fn main(@builtin(global_invocation_id) GlobalInvocationID: vec3<u32>) {
    let x: u32 = GlobalInvocationID.x;
    let y: u32 = GlobalInvocationID.y;
    let dimensions: vec2<u32> = textureDimensions(input_texture);

    if (x >= dimensions.x || y >= dimensions.y) {
        return;
    }

    let kernel_size: i32 = i32(kernel.size);
    let half_size: i32 = kernel_size / 2;

    var color: vec4<f32> = vec4<f32>(0.0);

    for (var i: i32 = -half_size; i <= half_size; i = i + 1) {
        for (var j: i32 = -half_size; j <= half_size; j = j + 1) {
            let nx: i32 = i32(x) + i;
            let ny: i32 = i32(y) + j;

            if (nx >= 0 && nx < i32(dimensions.x) && ny >= 0 && ny < i32(dimensions.y)) {
                let pixel: vec4<f32> = textureLoad(input_texture, vec2<i32>(nx, ny), 0);
                let kernel_value: f32 = kernel.values[(i + half_size) * kernel_size + (j + half_size)];
                color = color + kernel_value * pixel;
            }
        }
    }

    color = color / kernel.sum;
    textureStore(output_texture, vec2<i32>(i32(x), i32(y)), color);
}";

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, bytemuck::Pod, bytemuck::Zeroable)]
struct KernelHeader {
    sum: f32,
    size: u32,
}

struct Kernel {
    sum: f32,
    values: Vec<f32>,
}

fn kernel(radius: u16) -> Kernel {
    let radius = radius as i32;
    let sigma = radius as f32 / 3.0;
    let mut values = Vec::new();
    let mut sum = 0.0;

    for y in -radius..=radius {
        for x in -radius..=radius {
            let distance = (x * x + y * y) as f32;
            let value = (-distance / (2.0 * sigma * sigma)).exp() / (2.0 * std::f32::consts::PI * sigma * sigma);
            values.push(value);
            sum += value;
        }
    }

    Kernel {
        sum,
        values,
    }
}

async fn blur(device: &wgpu::Device, queue: &wgpu::Queue, image: DynamicImage, radius: u16) -> DynamicImage {
    let rgba_image = image.to_rgba8();
    let (width, height) = rgba_image.dimensions();
    let input_data = rgba_image.into_raw();

    let cs_module = device.create_shader_module(wgpu::ShaderModuleDescriptor {
        label: Some("Gaussian Blur Shader"),
        source: wgpu::ShaderSource::Wgsl(GAUSSIAN_BLUR_SHADER.into()),
    });

    let kernel = kernel(radius);
    let kernel_size = (kernel.values.len() as f32).sqrt() as u32;
    let kernel_header = KernelHeader {
        sum: kernel.sum,
        size: kernel_size,
    };

    let kernel_data: Vec<f32> = kernel.values.clone();
    let kernel_buffer = device.create_buffer_init(&wgpu::util::BufferInitDescriptor {
        label: Some("Kernel Buffer"),
        contents: bytemuck::cast_slice(&[kernel_header])
            .iter()
            .chain(bytemuck::cast_slice(&kernel_data))
            .map(|x| *x)
            .collect::<Vec<u8>>()
            .as_slice(),
        usage: wgpu::BufferUsages::STORAGE | wgpu::BufferUsages::COPY_DST,
    });

    let texture_size = wgpu::Extent3d {
        width,
        height,
        depth_or_array_layers: 1,
    };
    let input_texture = device.create_texture(&wgpu::TextureDescriptor {
        label: Some("Input Texture"),
        size: texture_size,
        mip_level_count: 1,
        sample_count: 1,
        dimension: wgpu::TextureDimension::D2,
        format: wgpu::TextureFormat::Rgba8Unorm,
        usage: wgpu::TextureUsages::TEXTURE_BINDING | wgpu::TextureUsages::COPY_DST,
        view_formats: &[],
    });

    let input_texture_view = input_texture.create_view(&wgpu::TextureViewDescriptor::default());

    let output_texture = device.create_texture(&wgpu::TextureDescriptor {
        label: Some("Output Texture"),
        size: texture_size,
        mip_level_count: 1,
        sample_count: 1,
        dimension: wgpu::TextureDimension::D2,
        format: wgpu::TextureFormat::Rgba8Unorm,
        usage: wgpu::TextureUsages::STORAGE_BINDING | wgpu::TextureUsages::COPY_SRC,
        view_formats: &[],
    });

    let output_texture_view = output_texture.create_view(&wgpu::TextureViewDescriptor::default());

    let bind_group_layout_0 = device.create_bind_group_layout(&wgpu::BindGroupLayoutDescriptor {
        label: Some("Bind Group Layout 0"),
        entries: &[
            wgpu::BindGroupLayoutEntry {
                binding: 0,
                visibility: wgpu::ShaderStages::COMPUTE,
                ty: wgpu::BindingType::Buffer {
                    ty: wgpu::BufferBindingType::Storage { read_only: true },
                    has_dynamic_offset: false,
                    min_binding_size: None,
                },
                count: None,
            },
        ],
    });

    let bind_group_layout_1 = device.create_bind_group_layout(&wgpu::BindGroupLayoutDescriptor {
        label: Some("Bind Group Layout 1"),
        entries: &[
            wgpu::BindGroupLayoutEntry {
                binding: 0,
                visibility: wgpu::ShaderStages::COMPUTE,
                ty: wgpu::BindingType::Texture {
                    sample_type: wgpu::TextureSampleType::Float { filterable: false },
                    view_dimension: wgpu::TextureViewDimension::D2,
                    multisampled: false,
                },
                count: None,
            },
            wgpu::BindGroupLayoutEntry {
                binding: 1,
                visibility: wgpu::ShaderStages::COMPUTE,
                ty: wgpu::BindingType::StorageTexture {
                    access: wgpu::StorageTextureAccess::WriteOnly,
                    format: wgpu::TextureFormat::Rgba8Unorm,
                    view_dimension: wgpu::TextureViewDimension::D2,
                },
                count: None,
            },
        ],
    });

    let bind_group_0 = device.create_bind_group(&wgpu::BindGroupDescriptor {
        label: Some("Bind Group 0"),
        layout: &bind_group_layout_0,
        entries: &[
            wgpu::BindGroupEntry {
                binding: 0,
                resource: kernel_buffer.as_entire_binding(),
            },
        ],
    });

    let bind_group_1 = device.create_bind_group(&wgpu::BindGroupDescriptor {
        label: Some("Bind Group 1"),
        layout: &bind_group_layout_1,
        entries: &[
            wgpu::BindGroupEntry {
                binding: 0,
                resource: wgpu::BindingResource::TextureView(&input_texture_view),
            },
            wgpu::BindGroupEntry {
                binding: 1,
                resource: wgpu::BindingResource::TextureView(&output_texture_view),
            },
        ],
    });

    let pipeline_layout = device.create_pipeline_layout(&wgpu::PipelineLayoutDescriptor {
        label: Some("Pipeline Layout"),
        bind_group_layouts: &[&bind_group_layout_0, &bind_group_layout_1],
        push_constant_ranges: &[],
    });

    let compute_pipeline = device.create_compute_pipeline(&wgpu::ComputePipelineDescriptor {
        label: Some("Compute Pipeline"),
        layout: Some(&pipeline_layout),
        module: &cs_module,
        entry_point: "main",
        compilation_options: wgpu::PipelineCompilationOptions::default(),
        cache: None,
    });

    let mut encoder = device.create_command_encoder(&wgpu::CommandEncoderDescriptor {
        label: Some("Command Encoder"),
    });

    let input_buffer = device.create_buffer_init(&wgpu::util::BufferInitDescriptor {
        label: Some("Input Buffer"),
        contents: input_data.as_slice(),
        usage: wgpu::BufferUsages::COPY_SRC,
    });

    let bytes_per_row = ((4 * width + 255) / 256) * 256;
    let buffer_size = (input_data.len() as u64).max((bytes_per_row * height) as u64);

    encoder.copy_buffer_to_texture(
        wgpu::ImageCopyBuffer {
            buffer: &input_buffer,
            layout: wgpu::ImageDataLayout {
                offset: 0,
                bytes_per_row: Some(bytes_per_row),
                rows_per_image: Some(height),
            },
        },
        wgpu::ImageCopyTexture {
            texture: &input_texture,
            mip_level: 0,
            origin: wgpu::Origin3d::ZERO,
            aspect: wgpu::TextureAspect::All,
        },
        texture_size,
    );

    {
        let mut compute_pass = encoder.begin_compute_pass(&wgpu::ComputePassDescriptor {
            label: Some("Compute Pass"),
            timestamp_writes: None,
        });
        compute_pass.set_pipeline(&compute_pipeline);
        compute_pass.set_bind_group(0, &bind_group_0, &[]);
        compute_pass.set_bind_group(1, &bind_group_1, &[]);
        compute_pass.dispatch_workgroups((width + 7) / 8, (height + 7) / 8, 1);
    }

    let temp_buffer = device.create_buffer(&wgpu::BufferDescriptor {
        label: Some("Temp Buffer"),
        size: buffer_size,
        usage: wgpu::BufferUsages::MAP_READ | wgpu::BufferUsages::COPY_DST,
        mapped_at_creation: false,
    });

    encoder.copy_texture_to_buffer(
        wgpu::ImageCopyTexture {
            texture: &output_texture,
            mip_level: 0,
            origin: wgpu::Origin3d::ZERO,
            aspect: wgpu::TextureAspect::All,
        },
        wgpu::ImageCopyBuffer {
            buffer: &temp_buffer,
            layout: wgpu::ImageDataLayout {
                offset: 0,
                bytes_per_row: Some(bytes_per_row),
                rows_per_image: Some(height),
            },
        },
        texture_size,
    );

    queue.submit(Some(encoder.finish()));

    let buffer_slice = temp_buffer.slice(..);
    let (sender, receiver) = tokio::sync::oneshot::channel();
    buffer_slice.map_async(wgpu::MapMode::Read, move |result| {
        sender.send(result).unwrap();
    });

    device.poll(wgpu::Maintain::Wait);
    receiver.await.unwrap().unwrap();

    let data = buffer_slice.get_mapped_range();
    let result: Vec<u8> = data.to_vec();

    let blurred_image = ImageBuffer::<Rgba<u8>, _>::from_raw(width, height, result).unwrap();
    let dynamic_image = DynamicImage::ImageRgba8(blurred_image);

    drop(data);
    temp_buffer.unmap();

    dynamic_image
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let instance = wgpu::Instance::default();
    {
        println!("Available adapters:");
        for a in instance.enumerate_adapters(wgpu::Backends::all()) {
            println!("    {:?}", a.get_info())
        }
    }
    let adapter = instance
        .request_adapter(&RequestAdapterOptions::default())
        .await.unwrap();

    println!("Using adapter: {:?}", adapter.get_info());

    let (device, queue) = adapter
        .request_device(
            &DeviceDescriptor {
                label: None,
                required_features: wgpu::Features::empty(),
                required_limits: wgpu::Limits::default(),
                memory_hints: wgpu::MemoryHints::MemoryUsage,
            },
            None,
        )
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let image = image::open("test.png").unwrap();

    // Crop image
    let _128x128 = image.clone().crop(0, 0, 128, 128); // cropping at (width/2, height/2, width, height) also fails

    // Blur the image
    let success_blur = blur(&device, &queue, _128x128, 12).await;
    success_blur.save("test_128.png").unwrap();

    let blurred = blur(&device, &queue, image, 12).await;
    blurred.save("test_random.png").unwrap();
}

Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "wgpu-blur"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
image = "0.25.1"
wgpu = "22.0.0"
bytemuck = { version = "1.16.1", features = ["derive"] }
tokio = { version = "1.38.1", features = ["rt", "rt-multi-thread", "macros", "sync"] }

I tried getting help online, but there isn't much information I could find around using wgpu to manipulate native rust image structs.
